# Help combining 2 multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have been a long time reader here and never posted but I was wondering if somebody could help me out with a problem I am having...

I have 2 arrays which print like this:

```
$fields = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field] => NewField
            [label] => New Field
            [required] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field] => _Field2
            [label] => Field 2
            [required] => 0
        )

)



$fields_data = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 1
            [field_name] => New Field
            [db_name] => NewField
            [field_type] => text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 6
            [field_name] => Field 2
            [db_name] => _Field2
            [field_type] => text
        )

)
```

And I need to create an array which looks like this :

```
$new_arr = Array
(
    [NewField] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 1
            [field_name] => New Field
            [field_type] => text
            [label] => New Field
            [required] => 1
        )

    [_Field2] => Array
        (
            [field_id] => 6
            [field_name] => Field 2
            [field_type] => text
            [label] => Field 2
            [required] => 0
        )

)
```

So what happens is the db_name become the array keys and then the 2 array where the field matches the db_name combine into one array.

Here is some code I have been trying to work with but obviously it is not working for whatever reason (PHP isn't my strong point):

```
foreach($fields as $field){

    $new_arr[$field['field']] = array();

foreach($fields_data as $tkey => $tval) {


if($fields_data[$tkey]['db_name'] = $fields['field']) {

$new_arr[$field['field']]['field_id'] = $fields_data[$tkey]['field_id'];

    }
    }

    }
```

Obviously the above code would only create the field_id element in the array however as it is it isn't working. I think having the 2 loops is overwriting the field_id value each time. But as I said php is not my strong point so any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will take the two arrays you're given and turn them into the third. Hope it helps! Could probably use some tweaking, but hopefully it solves your problem.

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach( $fields as $field )
{
    foreach( $fields_data as $field_data )
    {
        if( $field['field'] == $field_data['db_name'] )
        {
            $new_arr[ $field['field'] ] = array_merge( $field, $field_data );
            unset( $new_arr[$field['field']]['field'], $new_arr[$field['field']]['db_name'] );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are merging 2 arrays with the equality of label in first array and field_name in second (but I have some doubt since you have both in result array) here is the right way to do it.

```
$newArray = array();
//create a map for o1 complexity
$fieldDataMap = array();
foreach($fields_data as $data){
    $fieldDataMap[$data['field_name']] = $data;
}
//walk over fields to fill newArray
foreach($fields as $field){
    $newArray[$field['field']] = array(
        'field_id' => $fieldDataMap[$field['label']]['field_id'],
        'field_name' => $fieldDataMap[$field['label']]['field_name'],
        'field_type' => $fieldDataMap[$field['label']]['field_type'],
        'label' => $field['label'],
        'required' => $field['required']
    );
}
print_r($newArray);
```

**edit:** this solution seems a bit overkill for only 2 records but when it comes to 100+ sized arrays this would benefit more and more with o1 complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both arrays have the same length and the elements are ordered:

```
$newArr = array();
for($i = 0; $i <= count($fields); $i++) {
    $idx = $fields[$i]['field'];
    $newArr[$idx] = array_merge($fields[$i], $fields_data[$i];
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I'm not exactly sure this is what I am looking for though... What if the arrays are in a different order? I think I need to ensure that db_name=field before I create the array. I also get an error when I run this code of - Undefined offset: 2 on the line `$idx = $fields[$i]['field'];`. Thanks